# Getting which element has focus on a table of inputs

Tags: blazor, blazor-hybrid

I have a table with inputs of numbers in each cell.
I would like to change the value of the inputs with the mousewheel only if the input has the focus.
As far as I kown it is not possible to find which element has the focus in Blazor, you need to use Javascript.
So I tried to use JSInterop.
Here is the code for creating the first row of the table

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Amp</th>
                @for (var i = 0; i < AntArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    var j = i + 1;
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" value="@AntArray[i].Amp.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"
                           step="0.01"
                           @ref=TestRef 
                           @onmousewheel="(e)=>MouseScroll(e, j)"
                           @onchange="(e)=>UpdateData(e, j)" />
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
```

Here is the outcome with the focus on one input as example
[image]

As a first step to achieve my goal I try to set the focus on one input with a button.
So I have added the button "Set focus on Amp cell 1" as shown below

[image]

A click on "Set Focus Amp cell 1" lauches the following function

```
async Task SetFocus3()
{
    FocusOn = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("setFocus2", TestRef);
    Debug.WriteLine(TestRef);
}
```

The javascript function setFocus2 is as below

```
function setFocus2(element) {
element.focus();

var focusOn = (document.activeElement === element);
return focusOn;
```

}

As a check I return a bool true if the element has the focus which is displayed on the html page with the code

```
<p>Is focused : @FocusOn</p>
```

Of course, currently only the last cell can get the focus because on how the TestRef variable is assigned.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < AntArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    var j = i + 1;
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" value="@AntArray[i].Amp.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"
                           step="0.01"
                           @ref=TestRef 
                           @onmousewheel="(e)=>MouseScroll(e, j)"
                           @onchange="(e)=>UpdateData(e, j)" />
                    </td>
                }
```

Now I made the following changes to be able to set programmaticaly the focus on an input.

```
ElementReference TestRef;
ElementReference[] TestRefTab = new ElementReference[10];

@for (var i = 0; i < AntArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    var j = i + 1;
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" value="@AntArray[i].Amp.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"
                           step="0.01"
                           @ref=TestRefTab[i] 
                           @onmousewheel="(e)=>MouseScroll(e, j)"
                           @onchange="(e)=>UpdateData(e, j)" />
                    </td>
                }

async Task SetFocus3()
{
    FocusOn = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("setFocus2", TestRefTab[0]);
    Debug.WriteLine(TestRefTab);
}
```

But now a click on "Set focus on Amp cell 1" gives the following error

[image]

I don't understand what's happening?
Has someone an idea?
Maybe there is a more easy way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Isn't changing a number input with mousewheel standard on all modern desktop browsers?

Comment: I forgot to add that you need to need to add  `onmousewheel=""` to the `body` element of your index.html to enable it. Works in Webview2, which I guess you are using.

Comment: Thank you Mister Magoo. The issue I have now is that it scrolls first the page and then it changes the input value. Is it possible to change this behaviour? Is it possible to inhibit page scrolling if the focus is on an input?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my code.
I have to use the local variable j in TestRefTab as shown below.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < AntArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    var j = i + 1;
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" value="@AntArray[i].Amp.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"
                           step="0.01"
                           @ref="TestRefTab[j-1]"
                           @onmousewheel="(e)=>MouseScroll(e, j)"
                           @onchange="(e)=>UpdateData(e, j)" />
                    </td>
                }
```